# How to link subdirs lib with QMake?

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I have a Qt project (called "scanner") built with QMake, where I have 2 subprojects : a static library called "scannerlib" and an application using that lib, called "app" (which, at the moment, is just a main.cpp file)

My "scanner" folder contains the file scanner.pro :

```
QT += core testlib
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++14
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS = app scannerlib

app.depends = scannerlib
```

And two subfolders, containing a .pro file and source file related.
scannerlib/scannerlib.pro :

```
TARGET = scannerlib
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib

#I ommited SOURCES and HEADERS here for brevity
```

app/app.pro :

```
TARGET = app
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES = main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += ../scannerlib
LIBS += -L../scannerlib -lscannerlib
```

I successfully build libscanner, but I can't link it in "app".

> error : cannot find -lscannerlib

After checking, libscannerlib.a has been successfully built, so it should not be a problem.
If I remove -lscannerlib, I get an undefined reference. Which seems legit.

I can get a successful build if I move the created "libscannerlib.a" from the build folder to scanner/scannerlib, which allows qmake to find it.

So, the problem looks like it comes from "-L../scannerlib". What should I put there in such a way that qmake find the lib in the build folder ?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `DESTDIR` in your both `scannerlib` and `app` projects.

scannerlib/scannerlib.pro :

```
TARGET = scannerlib
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib
DESTDIR = ../bin
```

app/app.pro :

```
TARGET = app
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES = main.cpp
DESTDIR = ../bin
INCLUDEPATH += ../scannerlib
LIBS *= -L$$OUT_PWD/$$DESTDIR -lscannerlib
```

Comment: need to use `$$PWD/../bin` instead `../bin`, dont know why.